# How can I place two divs in one row of a vertically sorted flex div?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is my code snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.fruits {
  order: 2;
  background: #ff5423;
}
.container :not(.fruits) {
  order: 1;
}
.flowers {
  background: #f970bd;
}
.trees {
  background: #049500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fruits">The fruits</div>
  <div class="flowers">The flowers</div>
  <div class="fruits">The fruits</div>
  <div class="trees">The trees</div>
  <div class="fruits">The fruits</div>
</div>
```

I am putting all `.fruits` div in the bottom using `flex-direction: column;`. There are two other divs `.flowers` and `.trees` which can be placed randomly anywhere inside `.conatiner` and I can't handle that. I want them to take half of its parent width so they take only one row.

*What I want to achieve:*
[image]

Giving 50% width will not work here. I know the rule says the direction is column-wise, however, I still hope if there is any available method/trick to do so! Any other workaround using different technique rather than using flex will also help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with `flex-direction: row` you just need to set `flex-wrap: wrap` on parent and `flex: 0 0 50%` on elements you want to take half width.

You also need to use `* {box-sizing: border-box}` for paddings and `calc()` for margins.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 10px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.fruits {
  order: 2;
  background: #ff5423;
}
.container div:not(.fruits) {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
}
.flowers {
  background: #f970bd;
}
.trees {
  background: #049500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fruits">The fruits</div>
  <div class="flowers">The flowers</div>
  <div class="fruits">The fruits</div>
  <div class="trees">The trees</div>
  <div class="fruits">The fruits</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! You rock! :)